# Inline form elements being pushed down by collapsible menu

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap 5 form that is inline and which has a collapsible menu.
I am having difficulty stopping the collapsible advanced search menu pushing box 1 and 2 down (see code snippet).
I have set the .collapse with position absolute but this messes up the layout (the dropdown menu doesnt span 100% and box 1 and 2 kind of jump when the advanced search is clicked). You may need to view the snippet in full page mode to see the problem clearer.I have set the .collapse position to absolute but this does kind of disrupt the layout of the dropdown menu. Any help with getting this sorted would be much appreciated. Have been stuck on this form for ages!

```css
.collapse{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}

.search-form{

border:2px solid #000;

}
```

```html
<Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<!--Search form-->

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 bg-white search-form ">      

      <form action="" class=" form-inline d-flex">

      <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
  <div class="col-auto">
<a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" class="advanced">
    Advance Search With Filters <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a><div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
      
     <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Property ID" class="form-control">
            
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by MAP">
            
        </div>
         

         <div class="col-md-4">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Country">
            
        </div>
         
     </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" class="form-control" placeholder="box1" aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline">
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" class="form-control" placeholder="box2" aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="passwordHelpInline" class="form-text">
      Must be 8-20 characters long.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

    </form>
  </div>          
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Bootstrap5 JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Can you please try this code may be this can be helpful to your question.

```css
.search-form{
  position: absolute;
  border:2px solid #000;
  
}

.collapse {

  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<!--Search form-->

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 bg-white search-form ">      

      <form action="" class=" form-inline d-flex">

      <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
  <div class="col-auto">
<a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" class="advanced">
    Advance Search With Filters <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a><div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
      
     <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Property ID" class="form-control">
            
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by MAP">
            
        </div>
         

         <div class="col-md-4">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Country">
            
        </div>
         
     </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" class="form-control" placeholder="box1" aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline">
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" class="form-control" placeholder="box2" aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span id="passwordHelpInline" class="form-text">
      Must be 8-20 characters long.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

    </form>
  </div>          
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Bootstrap5 JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for suggetion. Unfortunately box 1 and 2 stilll gets pushed down when the collapse is expanded...strange thing is they dont when the viewport is reduced?

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: @hollie as i shared the screenshot of viewport can you tell me it is correct or not?

Comment: Hello, apologies for belated reply. Tried your code on another website i was having problems with. Works fantastically-thank you!!!:)